# Page service in spartacus?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

If `CMSService.getComponentData()` is to get the component data (`Component Controller` in swagger).

May I know what service is needed to get page data with list of CMS content slots (`Page Controller` in swagger)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CmsService` from the core lib provides a method to get the *current* page, based on the current route:

`CmsService.getCurrentPage()`

This returns an observable with a `Page`.

Under the hood, the page is *selected* based on the page *context*, which has a page type (product, category, content) and id (product code, category code, search query).